# Memory Leak in Propertylist Serialization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

Now it's time for me to ask a question. Until now I just ignored that Memory Leak. But now it's to find out which object leads to this leak.
 I have the following code:

```
 NSDictionary *addressDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&anError]];
```

At a later Point I also release the addressDic. 
If I use Instruments to detect Memory Leaks I get one at above posted code. I'm leaking about 16 Bytes and the objecttype is NSCFString. Why?

I hope you can help me.

Sandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `-release` the `anError` variable if there is an error.

Comment: WoW. That's it. And i thought that's really a braintwister. xD Thank you.